# Print job from Ubuntu to Windows printer held

Tags: printing, samba

I'm trying to print from my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop to a Samsung SCX-3401 printer installed on a Windows desktop. The printer installs just fine as a Samba printer, but when I try to print to it, the job is shown as "held".

I checked the job in http://localhost:631/printers/Samsung-SCX-3400 and found that the job status was as follows.

held since
Sat 03 Dec 2016 11:56:28 AM IST 
"NT_STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS opening remote spool Test Page"

Choosing "Release job" doesn't work. Any ideas?

This is a new problem since just today. Possibly after the latest updates. I could print to the printer (though only from PDF document reader) before. How can I roll back updates so as to check whether something has broken in the update?

Comment: Try  printing a test page from you ubuntu printer console.

Comment: Thanks, George. I already tried that, but to no avail. In fact, the output above is for the test page job.

Comment: Do you have samsung printer drivers  installed? If not install them from [here](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/) then try printing.